# How to upload laravel file to sever directory for test?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel framewrok for a project it is running fine on localhost but giving errors when I upload it to a directory on host

Warning: require(**DIR**/../bootstrap/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosoraweb187/b1812/ipg.girdtechnologiescom/test/acekamp1/public/index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.2.17/lib/php') in /hermes/bosoraweb187/b1812/ipg.girdtechnologiescom/test/acekamp1/public/index.php on line 21

I am using ipage host.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

In short - you have to upgrade PHP to 5.3 at least. The reason is because ***__DIR__*** is a magic contstant that is only added in PHP 5.3.

[Here is the explanation of the problem](http://www.neontsunami.com/posts/laravel-4-requires-php-5.3+)

Comment: Actually, the minimum requirement for Laravel 4 is PHP 5.4

Comment: @lukasgeiter it is for Laravel 4.2. For Laravel 4.0 minimum requirement is 5.3.7 But still - of course I should have pointed that the higher version of PHP is preferable. Thank you lukas.